# Is there a way to UDF in snowflake SQL language

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Below is the sample function and getting error at the variable declaration.

Is there a way to implement this declaration part in SQL UDF. Appreciate your Help!

```
create or replace function myprocedure2()
  returns varchar
  language sql
  as
  $$
      declare
      radius_of_circle float;
      area_of_circle float;
    begin
      radius_of_circle := 3;
      area_of_circle := pi() * radius_of_circle * radius_of_circle;
      return area_of_circle;
    end;
  $$
  ;
```

Comment: The short answer is no. The syntax you're using is available only in Snowflake stored procedures, not UDFs. If you need to define variables and use them, you'll need to use a JavaScript or Java UDF. You can use literal values and specify data types in a SQL UDF, but not define variables for later reference.

Comment: Why cant you pass the variable as function argument and if its a static or constant value then just use the constant value and multiply same with pi(). Refer following example - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/udf-overview.html#sql

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ADDWORKDAYS (StartDate date,WorkDays float,FactoryID varchar(2))
RETURNS date
LANGUAGE Javascript
AS
$$
function dd(input)
{
var D = $StartDate;
var WorkDays_Rem = $WorkDays;

var dminx = snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: "SELECT MIN(DateID) FROM OTD_CALENDAR" } );
var dMin = dminx.execute(); 
var dminy = snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: "SELECT MAX(DateID) FROM OTD_CALENDAR" } );
var dMax = dminy.execute();

Comment: Im trying to implement the above one but facing the error at var D = $StartDate; var WorkDays_Rem = $WorkDays

Comment: Post your code in question. As of now, its not clear what are you using the variables for in whatever code you have posted. All I can see is select min and max date from a table with NO where condition. So not sure what are variables being used for ! Also, remember while porting you need to consider the target environment (snowflake in this case) and work as per its features and limitations, so it may not be 1-to-1. You cannot do multi calculation in snowflake udf,(not supports multi-lines) if that is what is needed then as @Greg mentioned you are better off using Snowflake stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the most idiomatic way to do this in SQL would be to create a nested query in which every variable becomes a comuted (aka derrived) column:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myprocedure2()
  RETURNS FLOAT
  LANGUAGE SQL
  AS
  $$
    SELECT area_of_circle FROM
    (SELECT 
        3 AS radius_of_circle,
        PI() * SQUARE(radius_of_circle) AS area_of_circle
    )
  $$
  ;
 
SELECT myprocedure2();
```

Fortunately, in Snowflake SQL, computed columns can be based on other, previously computed columns of the same SELECT statement.

You could even do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myprocedure3()
  RETURNS FLOAT
  LANGUAGE SQL
  AS
  $$
    SELECT area_of_circle FROM
    (SELECT 
        3 AS radius_of_circle,
        radius_of_circle * radius_of_circle AS square_of_radius,
        PI() * square_of_radius AS area_of_circle
    )
  $$
  ;
 
SELECT myprocedure2(), myprocedure3();
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters to a function are "any case" in the function declaration

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ADDWORKDAYS (StartDate date,WorkDays float,FactoryID varchar(2))
```

but inside the Javascript code, they are all upper case, thus are accessed as:
`STARTDATE`, `WORKDAYS`, & `FACTORYID`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ADDWORKDAYS (StartDate date,WorkDays float,FactoryID varchar(2)) 
  RETURNS date 
  LANGUAGE Javascript 
  AS 
  $$
  var D = STARTDATE; 
  var WorkDays_Rem = WORKDAYS; 
  return D;
  $$;
```

```
  select addworkdays('2022-05-26'::date, 25::float, 'ab');
```

| ADDWORKDAYS('2022-05-26'::DATE, 25::FLOAT, 'AB') |
| --- |
| 2022-05-26 |